# Mocking Autowired static field

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I am trying to mock a static Autowired Field but getting a null pointer exception in my testmethods on executing the JunitTest.
Below is my source and test class code snippet.

```
public class MyUtil {

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUtil.class);


private static MyLogger myLogger;

@Autowired
private MyLogger tMyLogger;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    ModelUtil.myLogger  = tMyLogger;
}

 public static String getSomething(String foo) {


    if (foo != null) {
        myLogger.log(foo);

    }
    }
```

MyLoggerTestClass is below:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyUtilTest {


private static MyLogger myLoggerMock;


@Mock
private MyLogger tMyLoggerMock;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    ModelUtilTest.myLoggerMock = tMyLoggerMock;
}
```

Comment: Mockito doesn't mock static classes. Not sure what you are attempting by autowiring a field and having a static one. If it works how would you know which one to use and when? Usually people don't test logging, it's a non-functional requirement of most software. Not saying you shouldn't, but it's not normally done.